# Flutter - TextFormField Crash App When Want to Change Initial Value

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I want to change my initial value from text form field...
when i try to edit my initial value my application gone crash
my TextFormField Code~:

```
TextField(
                          controller: emailController..text = email,
                        ),
```

my Email COntroller~:

```
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 emailController.value = TextEditingValue(
      text: email,
      selection: TextSelection.fromPosition(
        TextPosition(offset: email.length),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: where I used this?

Comment: in the method initstate()

Comment: there is no problem in email it will also crash on simple textediting when i try to edit my text